# JNI and Shared memory

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, posix, shared-memory

I use JNI to access shared memory segments previously created. I use a Java/Jni read/write function which could either take the address of the shared buffer, or the id of the mapped region.

Unfortunately, it seems like every time I call the read/write functions I have to remap the segment using the function below. Is there any way to get round this? I would like (i have tried this, but it didn't work, to only have to map  the segment once, and simply use the void* addr parameter in the future, as opposed to every time I call the JNI method read or write, to have to call map_shared_memory. The current code works well, but remains relatively slow. Hence the desire to minimise seemingly unnecessary operations.

```
void* map_shared_memory(int id) {
     void* addr;
     if (id == 0)
         return NULL;
     addr = shmat(id, NULL, 0);
     shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
     if(addr<=0) 
         perror("Error Mapping Shared Memory: "); 
     return addr;
```

}

Comment: uhmmm have you tried this -  http://clipc.sourceforge.net/ and this http://www.downloadplex.com/Linux/Developer-Tools/Components-Libraries/clipc-for-linux_406179.html

Comment: thanks,  but unfortunately using external libraries is not really an option.

Comment: *Why* do you have to re-map the memory for every access? In other words, what is breaking it? I haven't tried this yet, and it might not solve your problem either, but I would have assumed that it should be possible to make this shared memor available to Java as a [`NewDirectByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#new_direct_byte_buffer).

Comment: It would appear like the segment is getting destroyed when returning from JNI to Java, and going back from Java to JNI. Do you have an idea why?

Thanks, the NewDirectByteBuffer looks promising. Unfortunately, I'm using semaphores so have to do synchronisation at the JNI/C level.

Comment: I see no reason why the segment should get destroyed. Perhaps you can use `strace` to verify that, and if it really happens, use some debugger to locate the place in the code where that does happen. In my understanding, the JVM shouldn't even know anything about the segment, so it should have no reason to tamper with it.

Comment: If you are in a webserver or application server framework, perhaps each request is being run in a different thread/process/sandbox or whatever. Perhaps you could setup a unit test in boring old command-line mode and convince yourself your code is right before searching for what's complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a collaboration between a class ShmFactory which opens (or create) the Shared Memory and and ShmAccess which offer read/write methods.

```
interface ShmAccess
{
   void read( shmId, byte[] bytes );
   void write( shmId, byte[] bytes );
}

interface ShmFactory
{
   public native ShmAccess open( int shmId );
}
```